# Sphinx docs: table of contents skips to top when new page is "below the fold"

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I've a problem with the HTML I'm building from sphinx (version 3.4.3 -- I know it's old, this is for reasons beyond my control, although I've just tried rebuilding with v4.4.0 and I'm seeing the same issue).

My docs are for an open source project and they are stored [here](https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/tree/main/docs) but published [here](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

You can see a [video of what I'm dealing with here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orW1_vmOxNY).

To describe it -- when I select a page that is "below the fold" in the table of contents (by scrolling down) the toc jumps back up to the top and hides my selection. I can scroll down to find it, and navigate within the page using section links in the toc, and all is fine. But if I select another page below the fold, again it jumps to the top.

It's really disorienting for a reader to lose their place.

Is this a known bug? I can't work out how to fix it.

I've tried various HTML theme settings like the `sticky_navigation` setting in `conf.py` but that doesn't change anything.

I tried upgrading Sphinx to v 4.4 but that didn't help either.

I'm using the RTD theme but have no choice in that.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to this question (my colleague resolved it for me)

It's related to the `sphinx-rtd-theme` -- version 0.4.1 introduced it and bumping it to 1.1.1 solves the issue (it was solved in 0.4.3 AFAICT).